# Прошу помочь с админко джанго

Tags: django

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Вендор', max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описания', blank=True, null=True)
    avaible = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Публикация', default=False)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вендор'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вендоры'
        ordering = ('-date_create',)


class VendorMenu(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Меню', max_length=255)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вендор Меню'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вендоры Меню'
        ordering = ('-order',)


class VendorFood(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor_menu = models.ForeignKey(VendorMenu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название', max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описания', blank=True, null=True)
    avaible = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Публикация', default=False)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вендор Еда'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вендоры Еда'
        ordering = ('-date_create',)
```

ВедорМеню ссылается на Вендор

когда хочу добавить объект ВендорФуд в админке, при выборе Вендоре, появляется все ВендорМеню которые существуют, как сделать так когда при выборе Вендор, пусть появляется только те ВендорМеню которы ссылается на определенный Вендор, прошу помочь! спасибо

Comment: Замените изображение текстом.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev исправил

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как исключить не нужные объекты ВендорМеню?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev прошу помочь, не могу разобраться в документе, тем более на англ языке, прошу помочь, что нужжно в файле admin прописать